# Extending $ref with additional required fields

Tags: jsonschema

Given a part of a schema called `location` like this:

```
{
  type: 'object',
  required: [ 'country' ],
  additionalProperties: false,
  properties: {
    country: {
      enum: [ 'DE', 'CH', 'AT' ],
    },
    postalCode: { type: 'string' },
  },
};
```

In most of our use cases a location is valid given only a country code. However we have a few occasions where we have to require a ZIP code as well.

A company in our case for example will always require a postalCode. Our previous `location` schema does not enforce this of course. Other schemas require location objects that do not enforce presence of a postal code. This is our company schema:

```
{
  type: 'object',
  required: [ 'name', 'location' ],
  additionalProperties: false,
  properties: {
    location: { $ref: 'location' },
    name: { type: 'string' },
    website: { type: 'string' },
  },
};
```

Is there a way in JSON Schema to use a $ref but also extend it so that the `location` property in the `company` schema will automatically require a `postalCode`? Our current solution is to create a second schema based on `location` where we simply changed the `required` attribute, but I'm hoping there is a better way.

Thank you.

Comment: These are the available options: https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/issues/134#issuecomment-242989744. It's not exactly about extending "required", but similar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can

```
{
  type: 'object',
  required: [ 'name', 'location' ],
  additionalProperties: false,
  properties: {
    location: {
      allOf: [
        { $ref: 'location' },
        { required: [ 'postalCode' ] }
      ]
    },
    name: { type: 'string' },
    website: { type: 'string' }
  }
}
```