# How do I add additional constraints to a property in a referenced schema in JSON Schema?

Tags: geojson, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to write a JSON Schema to impose additional required properties in a referenced schema. I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60673675/apply-addtional-constraints-to-a-refered-definition-in-json-schema) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958392/extending-ref-with-additional-required-fields), but `check-jsonschema` tells me that I need the properties in the top level, not in the nested `properties` object.  How do I add a constraint on a nested object property?

Attempted schema:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "https://example.com/sample.schema.json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "boundaries": {
      "description": "Boundaries",
      "allOf": [
        { "$ref": "http://geojson.org/schema/Feature.json" },
        {
          "geometry": {
            "oneOf": [
              { "$ref": "http://geojson.org/schema/MultiPolygon.json" },
              { "$ref": "http://geojson.org/schema/Polygon.json" }
            ],
            "additionalProperties": false
          }
        },
        { 
          "type": "object",
          "required" : ["name"]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like the following to succeed, but the above validator asks me to put `name` at the same level as `type`, `properties`, and `geometry`.

JSON instance:

```json
{
  "boundaries": {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "name": "Bounded Place",
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [ -100.0, 40.0 ],
          [ -100.0, 45.0 ],
          [ -110.0, 45.0 ],
          [ -110.0, 40.0 ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues with the attempted schema

- the `$schema` declaration for draft-07 must use `http` rather than `https`. This is not considered to be a network reachable uri, but rather an identifier for the meta-schema.  *src: [draft-07 spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-5)*
- the second `allOf` subschema doesn't define the property `geometry` correctly. This schema is completed unconstrained and will allow any data to pass. You can only constrain properties with the `properties` keyword defined. Did you want to add additional validation on the geometry keyword that the referenced schema doesn't validate?
- `additionalProperties: false` in the second subschema will also make this entire schema fail any instance because ALL subschemas of an `allOf` must be valid. There are two reasons why this will fail. Firstly, when `additionalProperties:false` is defined with any composition keyword (allOf, oneOf, anyOf), and no `properties` keyword is defined, the schema will never pass any data instance because the additional properties are constrained at the root schema and it does not "reach into" the `oneOf` array of subschemas, so it's not aware of any defined properties at the root, thus it fails any attempt to validate any schema. Secondly, When you constrain one of the subschemas to no additional properties inside an `allOf`, if the properties from the other subschemas are not defined in the schema with `additionalProperties: false`, all of the schemas will fail.
- you have `required: ["name"]` at the wrong nested level because the `Feature.json` schema has a property called `properties` (which can be confusing) and this is where you have defined `name` in your instance.

From my understanding, you want to require `name` in your data instance. To do this, you need to define the nested structure in an `allOf` subschema and then require that property. Because the property `properties` is defined in the geoJSON schema and it appears that is where you want this requirement, this is how you would achieve that.

#### JSON Schema definition

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "https://example.com/sample.schema.json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "boundaries": {
      "description": "Boundaries",
      "allOf": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "properties": {
              "required": [
                "name"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$ref": "https://geojson.org/schema/Feature.json"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

#### data instance

```json
{
  "boundaries": {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "name": "Bounded Place"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [ -100.0, 40.0 ],
          [ -100.0, 45.0 ],
          [ -110.0, 45.0 ],
          [ -110.0, 40.0 ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Clarified a number of points I was struggling through.  Thanks much!

Comment: feel free to jump into the [Slack](https://join.slack.com/t/json-schema/shared_invite/zt-1rptj13ch-ZygpGVq7jUxQYpct0vwsGQ) if you have any other questions.